# Jsoup HTML Pattern matching in a javascript code block?

Tags: android, parsing, html-parsing, pattern-matching, jsoup

I am parsing a HTML document and need to extract the 2 addresses after location.href= and window.location= from a javascript block.

```
if (countDownTime <= 0){
location.href="http://192.168.2.254:1000/keepalive?06050f020b0b524d";
return;}


function logout(){
window.location="http://192.168.2.254:1000/logout?06050f020b0b524d";
}
```

how can i do this in Jsoup. please post the code with required imports.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=(location\.href=")|(window\.location="))(.+?)(?=")`

or `((location\.href)|(window\.location))="(.+?)"` if your regex engine not support lookbehind/lookahead, your value would be in regex group

Comment: i don't know java, find class `regex` call method `matches`

Comment: i was getting issues with reges it was getting too complex. so i convert4ed my html inputstream as string and extracted my required fields using string.substring() using index numbers. but thans for your help. ciao